# What is wrong with this dynamic routing in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js

This might be a repeat question, and I might be doing this completely wrong in which case, excuse my lack of understanding for the moment. I'm currently building a Nextjs app with the plan to intergrade Shopify/Hydrogen but for now, scratch. I'm currently trying to build a dynamic link, using `<Link>` using the docs. See here: [Next/Link docs][1]

The Link contains an `<a>` child so that's why I'm assuming the necessity for the dynamic link. To do so, I've created the following constant:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'

const MyButton = React.forwardRef(({ href }, ref) => {
  return (
    <a href={href} ref={ref} className={styles.imgc}>
     <img
      className={styles.img}
      src="weatherbutton.jpg"
      width="100"
      height="50"> 
     </img>
     <div>&rarr; Weather</div>
    </a>
  )
})
```

Of which I then have the simple:

```
<Link href="/satweather" passHref>
 <Weather />
</Link>
```

As instructed in the docs. It is not being held within its own `<div>` but rather in a single `<div>` containing, what I hope will contain multiple Links. I may ultimately need to switch to making those into a `<ul><li>` but for now as is - unless that is necessary to the functionality.

Problem is I continued to receive a 404 error.
Under advisement, changed the `href=` to `href="/satweather" passHref>`

New error recieved:

````
  errno: -20,
  code: 'ENOTDIR',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: '/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/pages/satweather.js/index.ts'
}```

As a follow up: Since the page I am trying to port in is a client file, would I need to then add a separate folder for the shop server pages or will placing under the api folder work? Can I create it in a different folder, then do a general js that includes only to export the server items?



  [1]: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link
````

Comment: If you want the route accessible at `/satweather` then rename the folder to `/satweather/index.ts` (drop the .js).

Comment: So if I create a folder ```satweather```, at this point I dropped the "sat" so its just "weather", then then the may file would be index.ts? or index.js? Would the following then be ```../weather/index``` or still just ```/weather```?

Comment: It could be either `/weather/index.js` or `/weather.js`.

Comment: Oh I see...
Which would explain why it didn't work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` should not link to the file in the `pages` directory, but rather the route relative to the base URL. So if you have a page called `satweather.js` in the pages directory, you would link to it as so:

```
<Link href="/satweather" passHref>
 <Weather />
</Link>
```

Comment: Did so. Dropped the .js.
Received a new error: 
```Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, access '/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/pages/satweather.js/index.ts'```

Comment: Full Error: ```error - [Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, access '/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/pages/satweather.js/index.ts'] {
  errno: -20,
  code: 'ENOTDIR',
  syscall: 'access',
  path: '/mnt/c/Users/root/Desktop/satrange/sat/pages/satweather.js/index.ts'
}
```

Comment: For clarification, is the `Weather` component that you have within the Link the `MyButton` component?

Comment: That is correct. I need, if this works, to have multiple so I changed the name to weather for better identification.

Comment: We have success!!
Will test three more times. If successful, will mark your question as the answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, good to hear!